# Can Google Analytics do a user's who looked at x also looked at y?

Tags: google-analytics

Just wondering if this this possible? I realise you could never use it to display recommendations on a page but it would be useful from an analytics point of view to see for example what other products user's who've looked at product x have also looked at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Advanced Segmentation](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=108040) to do this.

Advanced Segments slice Google Analytics data on the basis of sessions. Sessions are a collection of pageviews that correspond to the popular notion of a visit.

If you create an Advanced Segment for users who visited `/product/x/`, it will return data from all the sessions in which that page was viewed. (Similarly, you could create a segment for `/product/x` AND `/product/y`. From there, you could filter it to only include your product pages, and exclude the original products themselves.) As a result, this session-based querying is perfect for your use case.

So, yes, you could use Google Analytics API data to inform a simple recommendations engine. The only caveat I'd give is that the Google Analytics API is a little slow, so you'd want to cache the data locally in your app, rather than querying it directly on every pageload.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll definitely have a read up on that.